# Disable zoom on puffin browser

Tags: html, ios

I was looking to disable zoom on the puffin web browser on an iPad, and I came across this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

This tag disables zooming on safari on the iPad, but not on puffin. Is there something else I need to add to disable zooming on puffin?

Comment: That viewport tag looks all good; I'm guessing Puffin might refuse to respect that meta tag, and let users zoom in no matter what. A lot of websites misuse the ability to block users from zooming, so it wouldn't surprise me if a niche browser like Puffin was designed to let users override zoom-disabling.

Comment: puffin is incomaptible with the viewport meta tag i.e that is to say it doen't support screen.width and screen.height. it supports window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight though - maybe you could work with those?

Comment: http://toddmotto.com/viewport-dynamic-width-calculation-retina-and-pixel-ratio-javascript-widget/